# Reverse proxy with Acquia

Tags: wordpress, drupal, reverse-proxy, acquia

I have a Drupal based website hosted on Acquia. I want to have a WP blog hosting as a subfolder under the same domain name but actually residing somewhere else. So, it should look like http://myacquiawebsite.com/blog

I know I can achieve this with reverse proxy but I don't know how to do it on Acquia. Forward masking is another option but I need help in that as well.

Can anyone guide me what is the best way and how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Acquia supports mod_proxy which would allow you to do this.  You'll need to request that mod_proxy is enabled via a support ticket according to the instructions at: https://docs.acquia.com/articles/proxies-and-acquia-cloud#utilize